# ASP.NET on Mono - XMLHTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, ubuntu, asp-classic, mono

I'm completely new to asp classic and asp.net.
I have an unusual server configuration that I cannot change, and I also should replicate on a virtual machine.
In this configuration I have a working website, which is accessed by users through asp classic pages; those asp classic pages redirect the whole traffic to php pages. And the same in the opposite direction.
Now I have to replicate this whole mechanism on a server, a LAPP virtual machine: this implies that I should convert the asp classic code, into aspx / asp.net pages.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 - 64 bit, installed mono-complete, apache2, php5, libapache2-mod-mono, postgres ....

So I have the asp classic that says:

```
  Dim objHTTP
  Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  objHTTP.open "GET", strURL, false
  objHTTP.send ""
  Response.ContentType = objHTTP.getResponseHeader("content-type")
  Response.BinaryWrite objHTTP.responseBody
  Set objHTTP = Nothing
```

I translated the previous code, quite simply, as follows:

```
ServerXMLHTTP objHttp = new ServerXMLHTTP();
objHTTP.open("GET", @"127.0.0.1", false, null, null);
objHTTP.send("");
Console.WriteLine(srv.responseText);
```

And when I try to load my aspx page directly into web server (as suggested on the mono website as good practice for porting code) I get:

*CS0246: The type or namespace name `MSXML2' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?*

I tried using gacutil -i in order to add the two msxml6.dll and msxml3.dll libraries, copied from Windows environment (naive try, I know) but I really cannot find the right direction to follow. Any suggestion, simple guide or tutorial is more than welcome. In the meanwhile I will keep on looking for a solution. Thank you in advance.

Best.
GLB

Comment: MSXML on Linux? i don't think it possible

Comment: As Zam says - the *MS* should be a dead give away.

Comment: Well, probably you are right. Do you know if exist a way to make a "bridge" between the end-user and a php server? Something like an xml http request or similar in mono? Is this the right approach to the problem?

Comment: Well I tried with winetricks but it returns line 79 error. The whole thing is too tricky right now. I think I will follow a different approach: a linux vm on a windows machine with IIS installed. Thanks anyway for the answers and for your time.